# Проблема с PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Скачал PostgreSQL, все хорошо. Начал работать через SQL Shell, и он мне выдает вот такую ошибку на любую команду:
[image: Ошибка]

И в самом начале, при прощелкивании значений по умолчанию, после нажатия Enter у поля username выводит всегда вот это:
[image: Ошибка]

Я добавил в path путь к директории bin, но ничего не поменялось

Comment: Какую команду нужно выполнить?

Comment: @Oopss элементарно \l 
При любой команде ошибка